What is the best way to plot/visualize an expression of three unknowns?
I have the following simple expression
fun[x0_, x1_, x2_] = 4*x1*(x1 - (x0^2*x1*x2^2)/(-x1^2 + x2^2)^2); 

What is the best way to plot this information since there are three unknowns? Constraint: $X1>X2$.

This strongly depends on what you are trying to show or emphasize. You could use ContourPlot3D: ContourPlot3D[fun[x0, x1, x2], {x0, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}, {x1, x2, 2}, Contours -> Range[-3, 3], PlotPoints -> 20] or DensityPlot3D or SliceDensityPlot3D ...
